# Importing module/package from sister folder. Python 3.3, along with VSCode

Tags: python, import, visual-studio-code

Here's my hierarchy (note `__init__.py` is not needed in 3.3+):

```
SomeFolder/
    /SomePackage
        SomeModuleA.py
        SomeModuleB.py
    /SomeSmallProject
        SomeLogic.py
        SomeResource.bmp
```

Within `SomeLogic.py` I want to import the modules contained in /SomePackage

I've been doing this with `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "..")`, and this works. However I know it's hacky and I don't like it. Is there any other way of doing this properly? (other than editing PYTHONPATH)

Additionally, I cannot get VSCode to properly pylint and import using this method. So bonus points for anyone who can help me with that as well. Specifically VSCode does not update its search path after the `sys.path.insert()` hack.

Comment: FYI while `__init__.py` is not needed, it is strongly encouraged as you don't want namespace packages unless you explicitly have a need for them (they are subtly different).

Comment: Are you opening `SomeFolder` in VS Code as your workspace or the folder above it? And what are you executing to run this code (e.g. are you executing `SomeLogic.py` directly or some other script which imports `SomeLogic.py`?